# How does charge accumulate on a metal sphere moving through space with charged particles in it?

Tags: electrostatics

A question from space engineering: spacecraft move through a plasma environment that has up to $10^8$ electrons per cubic meter.  Often, references mention the energy of the  electrons as well (I believe it's upwards of 10KeV, although I'm not sure of the exact number).  Now, assuming that every electron that a spacecraft encounters will stick to its hull is not realistic - as charges accumulate on the skin of the spacecraft, they repel others.

I'm wondering if there is a model for how charge might accumulate on the skin of the spacecraft.  For simplicity, I'm happy to assume that the spacecraft is a uniform metal sphere (like sputnik more or less was).  How does the energy of  the electrons figure in to things?

Comment: If it is a plasma environment(by definition electrically neutral) why do you expect there to be a net charge accumulation? I suppose positively charged ions will have greater inertia - they can't "get out of the way" of a positively charged object; OTOH such an object would _attract_ electrons, which would move easily (low inertia). Intuitively the greater mobility of electrons will keep the object near-neutral. Can you give more background on the problem you are trying to solve? Do you actually mean "an electron gas" rather than a plasma?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I believe you are correct to assume it's an electron gas.  I do know that significant charge builds up on spacecraft, probably as it moves through clouds of electrons trapped in the Earth's magnetic field

Answer (score 1):

I found a fantastically useful reference [here](http://press.princeton.edu/chapters/s9500.pdf).

It describes how the higher velocity of electrons means that the rate of impact with an electron (the electron flux) is much greater than the rate of impact with a positively charged particle (in an otherwise neutral plasma), and that this results in net negative charge. There is some math there that shows how the energy of charged particles observed on board will be shifted (by $e\phi$) as a result of the net potential of the spacecraft.

The referenced article mentions *deep charging* as well: highly energetic particles can penetrate the outer layers, and end up embedded inside dielectrics inside the space craft.